# What is the Difference Between Double Curly `{{ }}` and Triple curly `{{{ }}}` in Mustache Template?

Tags: html, tags, mustache

I am using Mustache Template in my HTML DOM to generate some Dynamic contents.

I am using `{{ }}` inside **HTML tags** for that..

Now i want generate non HTML dynamic extension, for that i have `{{{ }}}`

But i dont know the difference between both.

so, what is the difference between these 2?

Comment: if you put '<b>john</b>' in {{name}} you get '&lt;b&gt;john&lt;/b&gt;' but if you put it in {{{name}}} you get unescaped html so  '<b>john</b>'.

Answer (score 2):

See the [manual](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html)

> The most basic tag type is the variable. A {{name}} tag in a basic
>   template will try to find the name key in the current context. If
>   there is no name key, the parent contexts will be checked recursively.
>   If the top context is reached and the name key is still not found,
>   nothing will be rendered.
>
> **All variables are HTML escaped by default. If you want to return
>   unescaped HTML, use the triple mustache: {{{name}}}**.